# JSF - Backend bean method is retriggered automatically after some time(5 minutes)

Tags: richfaces, jsf-1.2

I have below code in front end .xhtml file

```
 <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{backendBean.processRecords()}">
```

processRecords method functionality is to make 500 external webservice calls and stores some elements from response into Excel file which can be downloaded in front end once all 500 records are processed.But somehow when I clicked the button in front end before I get the response back, for every 5 mins processRecords() is triggered again , causing to go into infinite loop.

Could any one please suggest how to resolve this issue.

Comment: 500 webservice calls? Something's not right with that design. Are you positive you're running JSF-1.2?

Comment: yes we are using JSF 1.2 jars